# RegEx htaccess remove variable

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Sorry, but I couldn't find any help for my problem. Hoping you guys can help.

I have the url:
`http://example.com/many-pages?lang=xx`

I would like to turn that into just:
`http://example.com/many-pages`

Stripping away the "`?lang=xx`" where "`xx`" is the language code.
Also make it a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^?]*)\?lang=[^\s&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: It worked pretty well in my test. What is location of your .htaccess and are there more rules there? Make sure this is first rule in your .htaccess

Comment: I had moved it up to over my custom rules and it hadn't worked. Then I raised it to above WordPress rules and it's working. Do you think that might conflict with WordPress rules?

Comment: No it won't conflict with WP rules.